# What does this function do "override func `self`() -> Self"?

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services

I am reading AWS SDK sample code on [GitHub](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-ios-samples/blob/master/DynamoDBObjectMapper-Sample/Swift/DynamoDBSampleSwift/DDBDynamoDBManager.swift) and saw these following two functions:

```
// MARK: NSObjectProtocol hack

override func isEqual(object: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
    return super.isEqual(object)
}

override func `self`() -> Self {
    return self
}
```

This is only one comment above "NSObjectProtocol hack", which doesn't really make sense to me. Could anyone explain what they are trying to do here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a legacy code you can ignore when using the latest Swift. The earlier versions of Swift had issues recognizing that your mapper object indirectly inherits from `NSObject` and implements `NSObjectProtocol`. The current version of Swift does not have the issue, so you can safely ignore these two methods.

Answer (score 2):

This is an example of using a keyword as an identifier. You have to place backtick marks before and after the keyword to use it as such. According to [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/LexicalStructure.html) (under the Identifiers section)

> To use a reserved word as an identifier, put a backtick (`) before and after it. For example, class is not a valid identifier, but `class` is valid. The backticks are not considered part of the identifier; `x` and x have the same meaning.

The `// MARK: NSObjectProtocol hack` is used for commenting a section of code that allows Xcode to format the list of properties/methods etc. into groups.

Comment: But why? The point is that these functions literally do nothing but immediately call for `super` to handle it for them.

Comment: Maybe this class is not subclass of `NSObject` and there is need to be `NSObject` compliant? NSObject is a class but also a protocol.

Comment: I see. Looks like the object in question inherits the NSObject protocol, which requires the override.

Comment: Could you give a reference to "place backtick marks before and after the keyword"? And also, I don't quite agree with you edit -- I've tried it out, these two methods are not required. I don't have to override it for the code to compile.

Comment: Added the reference. I'll remove the edit regarding the overrides being required. It is possible that at one time they were required but if that is no longer the case they can be safely ignored.